# Cosa vuol dire a parità?

Tags: nouns

Poi  metto anche la frase per sapere perché si è usato il verbo  possa invece di posso

"A parità di questa geometria,  io possa fare blah blah...."

Comment: Penso sia ***parità***, con l'accento sulla à.  Il verbo potere è usato al congiuntivo (possa) in quanto probabilmente lo richiede la costruzione della frase... hai la frase completa?

Comment: @Gio grazie mille,  il resto non mi ricordo,  però penso che era una cosa come: io possa fare quello che hai detto tu,  potresti spiegarmi in modo più semplice?  Non ho capito ancora

Answer (score 4):

***[a parità di](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/a-parita-di)*** significa:

> - (loc.prep.) ***nel caso in cui vi sia uguaglianza di***: *a parità di prezzo questo è più vantaggioso*.

De Mauro

L'uso del congiuntivo "possa" dipende dalla costruzione della frase che sembra parte di un contesto più ampio.

Comment: Grazie mille, puoi fare un altro esempio, per capire la "possa"?

Comment: @Farzad64 "possa" = the "potere" (to can) verb . It's just coniugated in the conjunctive mode. You need a grammar text / the internet to look it up, it would take more than the space allowed in a comment to explain it. It's *roughly* equivalent to "I'd be able to"